# loop - reading text after a certain string up until a certain string

Tags: vb.net, loops, streamreader

```
start=AKS-RHzlSXSftLGYdBNk.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1&
```

For every instance of the word 'start' I need to be able to get the text after the first full stop, right up until the & symbol. E.g. 'eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1'.

There will be more than one instance of this. They will need to be appended to a listbox.

What is the simplest/quickest way to do this? (Using possibly streamreader - text file)

Comment: Does each instance of `start=` occur on a new line?

Comment: the file has random text within itself, but yes the `start=` begins on a new line. Just to let you know the file is roughly 500kb containing just under 33k lines.

Comment: 500KB is nigh on negligible if you follow the method I suggested, but thanks for adding that potentially important information.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and quickest way will be to read each line, and check if it `.StartsWith("start=")`. If so, then get the `.IndexOf(".")` and the `.IndexOf("&", <whereever the first indexOf was>)`. Get the `.SubString` which encompasses those two values. I'm sure you can write the code yourself from that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this function with a button click, output text each line on a textbox. I am sure you can adapt this to your code.

```
  Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    txtResults.Text = ""
    Dim ParseString As String
    ParseString = "start=123341.23124&kjdshfkjsdaksdstart=1231.2321312&kadhskjashdkjastart=1231.23126789898&skjdfhkjsd"
    Dim Delimiters() As String = New String() {"start="}
    Dim Words() As String
    Words = ParseString.Split(Delimiters, CompareMethod.Text)
    For Each Part In Words
        Dim Middle As String
        Middle = Part.Split(".").Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()
        Dim Good As String
        Good = Middle.Split("&").FirstOrDefault()
        txtResults.Text += Good + vbNewLine
    Next
End Sub
```

Output was

```
23124
2321312
23126789898
```

Added 31104 lines to a string and ran, took about 11 seconds to run on my laptop. Might be too slow for your app?

Comment: It seems reasonable to assume that the OP has a fair amount of text to extract, so a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be more "performant". Also, appending text incrementally to a UI control is very much *not* the fastest way of accumulating a string.

Comment: thats not quite what the OP is after.  they are after the text after the `.` after `start`.  The OP refers to it as a `full stop`.

Comment: this was just for a test to output to a UI control, as I didnt want to write any code that would not execute in some sort or fashion. The first loop could be a new line, or some other string if that is how the text is split up.